# what standard says what classes should an implementation of Java SE contain?

Tags: java

I guess that each Java SE implementation must contain java.util.ArrayList class, java.util.Date class and many others. I guess that each Java SE implementation must contain them, because the implementation that Oracle publishes on their websites contain them. But is there a standard (I think: some JSR document) saying which classes each Java SE implementation must contain? I thought it is in JSR 337, but I read JSR 337 and did not found such information there.

Comment: You wont find every JSR within JDK. You will need to download seperate jars for them.

Comment: I think maybe you're looking for the API specification -- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/

Answer (score 1):

The java SE [apidoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/) describes all the classes in java SE. Any jre must provide these classes.

Answer (score 1):

The specification you're after, for the Java 8 release, is JSR 337, Annex 2. This contains:

> an annotated API specification showing the exact differences relative to Java SE 7.

It's available as part of the [JSR-000337 Java™ SE 8 Release Contents
(Final Release)](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr337/index.html) (and [here](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~mr/se/8/java-se-8-fr-spec-01/apidiffs/index.html)).

Realistically, unless you have a specific interest in the JSR process, the [public Java SE Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/) is probably a better place to start.